# Can a comment be considered spam?

Tags: discussion, comments, spam, google

Can a comment be considered spam? If so, what makes a comments spam?

I'm not serious, but technically speaking, shouldn't comments such as "Google it first" be seen as comment spam? :)

Comment: `shouldn't comments such as "Google it first" be seen as comment spam? :)` um... no? Especially not when the OP should, you know, have Googled first instead of posting a question? I've heard it  rumoured that occasionally happens on Stack Overflow. Not sure whether I should believe it though

Comment: "Google it first" is not spam.. It's just not a constructive comment. [Click here for the best muscle growth pills](http://example.com/)

Comment: Spam is someone trying to make you click on something to buy a product or whatever... How can "you should do research" be considered spam? (Side note: if you're not serious... Why open a meta question?)

Comment: On this site, we nuke spammers from low orbit. Their accounts are usually destroyed and we issue IP blocks. Thats in no way appropiate for the (admittedly often unconstructive) "google it first" comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Differentiate between "spam" and "noise".  Spam exists to promote a product or otherwise garner clicks to a site that you're probably not intending to go to; noise distracts from the actual problem at hand.

If you see a comment that reads something like, "Just Google it", you can safely flag it as "not constructive" (and in some cases, "rude or offensive" since the perceived tone is dismissive to the OP).

If you see a comment that reads "Google it first", I'd still encourage you to flag it as "not constructive", since it doesn't *do* anything except make the OP feel twice as bad; bad for asking the question and bad because they have now been shamed into defending why they asked the question.

Since comments are temporal, it's important to keep in mind that their purpose is to help us ask questions of the OP to ensure that we're not missing some piece of information and that they've given us all we know so that their question can be answered.  Off-the-cuff remarks to tell them to "go do their research" aren't the preferred way to communicate this sort of thing if you want to; downvotes are better.

Answer (score -16):

Yes, it's spam, even if the user who wrote it didn't realize. The proper way to say that sentence without spamming would be to avoid specific search engines and say e.g. "search" or "use a search engine".
It might still be not constructive, though.

That company already spends too much money to advertise its products everywhere. I don't want to see even more propaganda in comments.

And of course, there is a variety of search engines which can work better than Google depending on the situation. Telling someone to search using a particular search engine makes no sense.

Comment: Do you really say "use a search engine" instead of "Google it" in everyday conversation?

Comment: @nrussell I prefer the less specific "search" if the context allows it. But I don't use "google" as a verb, basically because my principal search engine is DuckDuckGo, not Google.

Comment: I think you can safely use phrase "Google it" even if you use a different search engine. People will be more likely to understand this than if you tell them to "DuckDuckGo it".

Comment: "Hotbot it" is the only acceptable choice here, @nrussell.

Comment: Are you kidding me? "Google it" is probably used thousands of times every week on this site. Use some common sense please. For better or worse, the verb "googling something" has become so synonymous with using a search engine so search for something that its entirely not spam.

Comment: Vendettas or personal opinions of a particular search engine do not make something spam. BT spends a lot on advertising; I don't like them and I use another provider. That doesn't mean someone saying "I use BT" is spam.

Comment: @ArtOfCode There is a difference between "I use BT" in a single commentary and lots of people telling everyone to "Use BT" (and anyway I think I have never seen a BT ad). Not sure if with "vendetta" you mean I'm a Google hater or something like that. That's not it, Google is a good search engine and is my secondary one. I'm just against arbitrary propaganda in comments just because people think that, since they love the Google search engine, it's not spam to tell everybody to use it.